# Как в resharper автоматически использовать все советы

Tags: visual-studio, jetbrains, resharper

Открыл одно большое решение со сотней проектов внутри. Resharper ругается на каждую вторую строку, и там есть на что ругаться. Хотелось бы использовать все советы решарпера во всех проектах. Но единственное, что я смог автоматически сделать для всего решение, это очистка ненужного кода. Но в коде очень много небольших мелочей: например, перемена или метод нигде не используется и его надо удалить, или советы по использованию тернарок или других более удобных синтаксических конструкций. Но все это можно исправлять только по одной проблеме за раз. Можно ли как-то автоматически исправить все такие проблемки во всех проектах?

Comment: Если решарпер накосячит, как потом это проверять то будете?

Comment: @Monk Но там очень много простых мелочей, в которых накосячить решарпер никак не сможет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще для массовых чисток в Решарпере есть инструмент Cleanup Code -- можно выбрать имеющийся профиль чистки или создать свой.

Но уж сколько я на своём веку рефакторил -- всегда предпочитаю руками делать. Да, работы больше, но и больше контроля за процессом. Если Решарпер накосячит или вы его не так поймёте -- исправлять-то вам.

Comment: Я пробовал в профиле Cleanup ставить все галочки. Но он все равно очень много пропустил. Например, неиспользуемые перемены так и остались, или предложение по тернарных операторах тоже не заюзались. Есть ли в Cleanup какие-то дополнительные настройки?